# How to disable ZoomOut effect in MenuFlyout

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In silverlight the context menu used to have a property `IsZoomEnabled` that use to define whether zoom out effect will be there when `ContextMenu` shows up but in winrt xaml we have `MenuFlyout` which does not have any such property. How should I disable this effect?

Here is the default template for MenuFlyout

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MenuFlyoutPresenter -->
<Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Light" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPresenterThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                  ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't accomplish this in WinRT. You can create your own `UserControl` or replicate the behavior of a `MenuFlyout` using only a `Flyout`. Try [this](http://timgabrhel.com/blog/flyout-on-windows-phone-8-1-runtime/) tutorial if you want to do something like this.

Comment: My Flyout is only popping up on top of the screen or botton. Isn't there a way to show it just under the button when I define it inside the Button.Flyout.